# installed certificate is not working in browser

Tags: 18.04, server, ssl

I have a **certificate.crt** file and installed it in Ubuntu using [this guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-ca-certificates-in-ubuntu-server/). I run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates -y    
sudo cp certificate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificate    
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

the result of last command was like this:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

But when I access the server link in my browser, it gives a certificate error like this:

[image]
Why is it doing so even the certificate is uploaded successfuly? I am unable to get the reason behind this.

Comment: Where did you get the certificate file? Was it issued by a known certificate authority or is it self-generated/self-signed certificate? If self-signed then you will get the warning above. You can click on advanced and then accept the risk/certificate which may be o.k. for you if you just want the certificate to use https on your site personally. If you have others accessing your site and you don't want them to see the warning then you will need to buy a certificate from one of the certificate authorities or via your ISP/web hosting company.

Comment: it is a self signed file

Comment: @codlord could you please give a reference for what you said for self signed certificate? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you just search online for `self-signed certificate warning` or `certificate authorities explained` but the general point of certificate authorities is they are meant to be a trusted third party that is meant to validate the identify of the person or organisation requesting the certificate. Browsers have lists of certificate authorities to validate against so I think the only way to stop the warning is to skip/accept the warning, have a certificate from one of the known authorities or add your own authority/certificate to the browser config.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the issue. have a good day

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here because they created their own Certificate Authority for (free) use in their ubuntu dev environments (in order to create and use your own signed server certificates). I followed the steps to get to update-ca-certificates just as OP did above. But Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu weren't finding my CA cert in the system wide location. They both require you to ADDITIONALLY use their menus to manually import them that way. This is different from Windows 11 as I didn't need to do anything special to Chrome or Edge for them to find my CA as valid.

For Firefox:
Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> Certificates -> View Certificates -> Import

- to Authorities if importing your Certificate Authority (CA) cert.